Senior citizen ladies solve crimes
I've read three or four ebooks about two ladies that are senior citizens solving crimes. They live in a place called "Tawas" I thought I'd saved them in my library but am unable to find them now. I tried googling using the word "Tawas" and still nothing. Unfortunately I can't remember the ladies names. They are friends. One is tall and slim the other is short and fat. They both fall in love and marry and then have adventures together.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Do they fall in love with each other, or with two other people?

The place name you remember as "Tawas" isn't actually "Botswana," is it?

Is this Agnes Barton Senior Sleuths Mysteries? I haven't read the books but the book description seems to be close, and there're several books in the series with the title containing "Tawas".

Agnes Barton Senior Sleuths Mysteries is a series of cozy mystery novels by American author Madison Johns. Agnes Barton is not your typical senior citizen from Michigan.


Trouble in Tawas  (2013)  Amazon.ca | Amazon.com
Treasure in Tawas   (2014)  Amazon.ca | Amazon.com
Bigfoot In Tawas    (2014)  Amazon.ca | Amazon.com
Scandal in Tawas    (2017)  Amazon.ca | Amazon.com
Tawas Goes Hollywood    (2017)  Amazon.ca | Amazon.com

From another link: Book Report: Agnes Barton Senior Sleuths Mysteries

Agnes Barton lives in Tadium, Michigan (which is a small town that is mostly made up of retired people) near Lake Huron and is a senior citizen. She is 72 years old. Agnes frequents Victoria Secret, drives a red mustang, sticks her nose where it does not belong, and is the fly in police officials Vaseline. Needless to say, she is not like most people's grandmothers.
On her cases, Eleanor Mason tags along; serving as a partner for Agnes. She carries a revolver (that comes in handy for the pair), flirts with anyone that she comes across (male or female), and tangles with her rival (Dorothy Alton); but at the same time is a lovable woman. She is also 82 years old and a major gossip.

